# Define some functionality that is stored in a variable

Tags: php

I am building a permissions system that works like this:

```
DEFINE ('CAN_POST', 1);
DEFINE ('CAN_READ', 2);

DEFINE ('IS_GUEST', '');
DEFINE ('IS_USER', CAN_READ);
DEFINE ('IS_MODERATOR', CAN_READ | CAN_POST);
```

Then I have a current user with some permissions like this:

```
DEFINE ('CURRENT', IS_MODERATOR);
```

And I check like this:

```
if (CURRENT & CAN_POST) print('CAN MAKE POSTS<br />');
if (CURRENT & CAN_READ) print('CAN READ STUFF<br />');
```

A **problem** begins here:

I need to fetch current user permissions from database and it is is of course a string. For example I will have in database something like: `IS_MODERATOR | CAN_REVIEW` which means that user has all permissions that `IS_MODERATOR` has `(CAN_READ, CAN_POST)` and in addition to this `CAN_REVIEW`.

How can I define `CURRENT` constant that will have **functionality of** `IS_MODERATOR | CAN_REVIEW` not just a string of it, which won't work.

Comment: `it is is of course a string.` of course you are wrong. it will be a nubmer. say, CAN_READ | CAN_POST would be represented as 3

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand, sorry. `$res = "IS_MODERATOR"; DEFINE('CURRENT', $res); print(CURRENT);` gives me a string `IS_MODERATOR`. not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it would be not a string but a nubmer.
Just assign your rights usual powers of two and use it as everyone.

Say, if `CAN_REVIEW = 4`, then `IS_MODERATOR | CAN_REVIEW` would be stored as 7

You'll be able even to check the rights right in the SQL query.

Or you can parse a retrieved value:

```
define('RIGHTS_CAN_REVIEW',4); //somewhere in config files
$rights = 7; //from database
define('CAN_REVIEW', (bool)$rights & RIGHTS_CAN_REVIEW);
```

now 'CAN_REVIEW' contains boolean `TRUE`
if `$rights` were 1 or 2 - there would be `FALSE`